# Delta Tables are been deleted but delta files are available at back end silver layer

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

Delta Tables are been deleted but delta files are available at back end silver layer

Method used is :  We are doing ingestion by loading parquet file from raw to silver, Deleting the delta folder every day , drooping the table  re creating when ever the job is executed.

Some times we do see the delta files are created in silver layer but in front end we are not able to see the table

Comment: Welcome! Right now it's not really clear what your question is, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77057165/edit) your question and specify what it is that you're asking?

Comment: You should probably avoid doing any file level operations against delta tables. Instead drop them using SQL

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you see the delta files but not able to see the table result
The possible reasons for getting empty results

- As you are dropping and recreating tables whenever the job is executing
- This could happen because of truncation of data in the table in between writing and reading the table.

[image]

You can use the below query to read Delta files directly using Spark

```
spark.sql("DESCRIBE DETAIL delta.`/your/delta/table/path`").show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

Deleting files directly from a Delta table may affect table integrity.
It's recommended to use the **VACUUM** command to delete files according to a retention policy.

Know more about [Vacuum a Delta table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum#vacuum-a-delta-table)
If you want to delete specific Delta files:

`dbutils.fs.rm("/your/delta/table/path/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.delta`"
You can use below query to see the operation performed on your tables.

```
%sql
DESCRIBE  HISTORY data_table
```

As you mentioned that delta tables are deleted, but you see delta files in silver layer.
The below command will help you list the files that make up a Delta table

```
describe_df =spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE  DETAIL  delta.`{delta_path}`")
display(describe_df)
```

[image]

It is better if you DROP tables using `%sql` than performing file level operations.

There are chances that, the data has been written to the Delta files but hasn't been flushed to the table yet. To ensure that all changes are visible, you can try running `OPTIMIZE` at file level and SQL table level as well.

`OPTIMIZE` does file compacting all part files into 1 file and as a reference to the latest snapshot of the delta table.
`OPTIMIZE`  removes unnecessary files from the transaction log.
`OPTIMIZE` makes no data related changes to the table, so a read before and after an `OPTIMIZE` has the same results.

Know more about [Compact data files with optimize on Delta Lake](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/optimize.html)

**Optimize SQL table:**

```
%sql
OPTIMIZE data_table
```

[image]

**Optimize the Delta Files in ADLS:**

```
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE delta.`{}`".format(delta_path))
history_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE  HISTORY  delta.`{delta_path}`")
display(history_df)
```

**Describe the history of the Delta table, Delta files including optimizations:**
history_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE  HISTORY  delta.`{delta_path}`")
display(history_df)
[image]